# Is there a way to monitor a folder for a file and execute a SSIS package without having to have VS/BIDS open?

Tags: t-sql, ssis, automation, wmi, bids

My first question on Stack overflow.

**Here's my problem:** I'm wanting to be able to execute a SSIS packages (on it's own) when a file has been placed in a folder. Preferably without the Visual Studio/BIDS application open. I also want it to reset itself after the package has run successfully so that it begins monitoring the folder again for the next day's file drop to repeat the process. After hours of research I haven't found any information on a complete "Lights-out" (No human interaction necessary) solution.

**Here's what I have so far:** I have a WMI component in my control flow monitoring the folder for the file, it works, but I still have to manually go into the project and then run it so that it will start the monitoring process and then  execute the data flow upon success. Data Flow consists of Excel source data, uploading to SQL database.

Please keep in mind, I am new to SSIS, teaching myself and it's only been about a  week. I apologize if this is a beginner type of question.

**Any ideas out there on a Lights-Out solution? I'm all ears.**

Comment: To automate packages you usually create a SQL Agent job - this is a SQL Server component so take a look in there.

Comment: If you are using SQL 2012 onwards (please specify), you can also use the integration services catalog and / or stored procedures to execute your package... so that's three methods you can use to execute it independently of BIDS

Comment: Thanks for replying. Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit). Unfortunately I do not have access to the SQL Agent Job. I'm not apart of IT, so they limit what I can/can't do.

Comment: OK next thing to try is windows scheduler and DTExec.EXE. You can use DTEXECUI.EXE to work out the command line required. Why are you building integrations if IT won't let you automate them?

Comment: Hi Nick, I just tried setting up the Windows Task Scheduler to execute the DTExec.EXE from a batch file, it ran, but it didn't seem to trigger the batch file though like it was supposed to due to a permissions issue. So, I did a little more research and was actually able to automate/fire the SSIS package through the Command Line using a VBA Macro. So I got it to work finally, but I know this is not the best way to do this.

Comment: So I'm going to work with IT to see if we can get a SQL Server Agent Job setup to run it instead. I originally thought I may have had some permissions that would allow me to do it, but turns out, that wasn't the case. It's been a great learning experience and I've learned a lot so I will consider it a win! Thanks for the help in presenting some options, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

1. **constantly monitoring / running**
   you may use 'For Loop Container'.
   add your file processing components into 'For Loop Container', let the for loop container run constantly.
2. **avoiding duplicate processing** 
   after the source file processed, you may use a 'File System Task' to 'Rename' your source file so that it'll not be processed again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file watcher task in ssis .

http://www.sqlis.com/post/file-watcher-task.aspx

or you can use WMI Event watcher task in your ssis package (which can trigger child package)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141130.aspx